# Percent Signs for Shell Vars to Remove Extension

Tags: shell, shell-script

```
for file in *.pdf ; do
    newname=${file%\\.\*}
done
```

I don't understand how the `%\.*` is removing the file extension, can someone walk me through it.

Comment: @jasonwryan: It's a bug, rather than a duplicate...

Comment: @lcd047 Read the edit history; as originally written it was a duplicate.

Comment: @jasonwryan: Heh, an incorrect edit _and_ a duplicate, oh my. :)

Answer (score 1):

> I don't understand how the `%\.*` is removing the file extension

That's because it doesn't. :) The code as written is wrong, and it doesn't accomplish anything useful.

There is a standard shell expansion `${variable%pattern}`, which takes `$variable`, and removes the *shortest* chunk at the end of it that matches `pattern` (there is a similar expansion `${variable%%pattern}` that removes the *longest* match).  However, `pattern` is supposed to be a shell glob, while the author of the piece of code above seems to have intended it as a regular expression.

The correct form is this: `${file%.*}`.  It works by removing everything to the right of the *rightmost* dot.  In contrast, `${file%%.*}` removes everything to the right of the *leftmost* dot.  For example, if `file=/some/very.long.directory.name/foo.pdf`, then `${file%.*}` expands to `/some/very.long.directory.name/foo`, and `${file%%.*}` expands to `/some/very`.